# Why does div without class limit width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using bootstrap to style a simple form I want two buttons aligned next to each other enclosed in a div container so I can position both of them side by side together. As soon as I enclose them in a div without any sort of class associated the width is limited and one button breaks to the next line. Why is this??

My [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/212744/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- Leave those next 4 lines if you care about users using IE8 -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div> <!-- Why does this div tag limit width? -->
                <button class='col-sm-12 col-md-2'>Cancel</button>
                <button class='col-sm-12 col-md-2'>Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <button class='col-sm-12 col-md-2'>Cancel</button>
            <button class='col-sm-12 col-md-2'>Save</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to enclose both buttons in a div and have them aligned next to each other. Can someone explain why a div tag would limit width?

Comment: I think you're being a little nit picky but I have updated the code to adhere to the guidelines.

Comment: So what is this supposed to look like. The classes you are using would make the elements 100% wide...not next to each other. I think this might be related to the issue.

Comment: At a large width they should be next to each other. If you look at the fiddle, the second pair of button are next to each other. I want it to remain the same way when I add a div around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Bootstrap's grid system as intended, you should follow this format:

```
<element class="container">  //Or container-fluid
  <element class="row">
    <element class="col-whatever">
    </element>
    <element class="col-whatever">
    </element>
  </element>
</element>
```

In other words, you need a container, then a row and then your columns. Your div between the row and the columns is the problem. There are numerous ways you can apply this to your html. Here's one way:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <button class='col-sm-12 col-md-2'>Cancel</button>
    <button class='col-sm-12 col-md-2'>Save</button>
  </div>


 <div class="row">
    <button class='col-sm-12 col-md-2'>Cancel</button>
    <button class='col-sm-12 col-md-2'>Save</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `div` placed within the first row is an immediate child element of the `row` class div. In Bootstrap 4, this element should contain column (`col(-breakpoint)(-width)`) classes, which is the case with the second row, whose buttons have column classes.

The unstyled div is therefore breaking the relationship between the `row` class and the buttons with the column classes, resulting in the undesired rendering seen in your fiddle.

The second row is therefore the correct implementation.